# Storing Posts&Comments in seperate tables or together

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was wondering what would be best, storing my comments in my post table or them having their own table?

My posts table only has an id, userid, image url and description of the post. I join the posts table with my users table to retrieve the name of the author.

Should I just add a new column to my posts table for comments and store a json of all the comments or should I create a new comments table and log either each comment as a separate row? I am not planning on adding fields to respond to people, just storing the comments. I'm assuming just adding another column would work fairly well.

If I stored the comments in the posts table then I wouldn't have to make a separate api call to gather them.

Thanks, would love to hear your ideas.

Comment: store in separate table... read over normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a relational database then right way is usage [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and 
[normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms). It means you should create two separate tables: posts and post comments

Comment: What would be best then, to have each comment be a separate row or have a json of all the comments? Separate rows would be easier to maintain and modify if the user needs to.

Comment: @ImJT each comment should stored in separate row

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `id_parent` column next to your `id` having the very same properties excluding the AUTO_INCREMENT and a DEFAULT to 0.

The given column can point to already existing `id` from previous posts. In case that this is a new post it can remain to the default value.

This will work in case that you will not constrain the new column with FOREIGN KEYS. You can set an INDEX if you require to search for faster all posts with replies.

That would also give you the flexibility to quote posts over posts over posts without the need to create new tables and searching all over the place. It might lack in normalization but it will save you time and effort in complexity.

Comment: that's a nice idea but I think in this case posts and comments are separate entities (i.e. one post can have many comments, but posts do not have parent posts)

Comment: thanks Adyson, it is entirely up to you. The idea behind this is to reduce complexity via joins. In case for instance that you use the same forms for posts and comments you will not have to implement 2 forms for the same thing. Well this is me, I like re-usability.

Comment: " for instance that you use the same forms for posts and comments" ...that would be pretty confusing to the user, no? Normally someone creates the post (blogger) and someone else writes comments (internet troll :-p) anyway, via a different UI. They are different entities. They probably have totally different fields and requirements about what content can be included, what attributes they have etc. A comment is usually a  much simpler entity than a post. I don't think it's a very practical suggestion. I'm all for re-usability, but not at the cost of clarity or accuracy.

Comment: The thing is that you can do whatever you like on how to represent the forms and the input. I prefer to keep the very same interface tweaking it with few if/else per case. For instance surely there is no title in the comment, or could there be? I mean it is nice sometimes to be able to identify what this comment is about. Also do you get thumbs up/down on the post and the comment? Can you set some links? From your example the only extra field that would separate a post from a comment is the imageURL. Do you need it for a post or could you add it in the description?

Comment: "from your example"... I think you're mistaking me for the person who asked the question. I'm just talking in general terms about blog posts. For instance in Wordpress a post is many times more complex than a comment which is appended to it. The OP has a simple example at present, but if they use their system much I'd bet heavily on it getting more complicated fairly quickly.

Comment: oops, my bad! :P... I am not talking about wordpress, It burns my eyes only to look at it! :P. You can achieve lets say N5. What would be the cost on the server to join 10 tables after you have achieved that and what would be the cost having an N3 with a single join? This is what I am talking about. Well it is not an entirely accurate example but you can do some performance checking with EXPLAIN EXTENDED